# In Ionic 3, Using Angular 5.2.9, HttpClient is not able to set headers for get requests, but can set headers for post request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient

package.json

```
{
  "name": "super-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.8",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

my code ->

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HandleError, HttpErrorHandler } from '../../common/providers/http-error-handler';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(        
    private httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler,        
    private auth: AuthProvider,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private businessConstant: BusinessConstant,
    private storeManager: StoreResourceManager,
    private util: Util) {
        this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('MyService');
}    

login(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Observable<StoreResource> {              
    let url:string = BaseUrl+'/test';
    let myHeaders : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization','dummy auth')
        .set('Content-Type','application/json');

    //Block (A)
    // return this.httpClient
    //         .post<StoreResource>(url, loginRequest,{headers:myHeaders} )
    //         .pipe( catchError(this.handleError('Login', new StoreResource() )));        

    //Block (B)
    return this.httpClient.get<StoreResource>(url, {headers:myHeaders})
        .pipe( catchError(this.handleError('Login', new StoreResource() ))); 
}  
}
```

In Block (A) I am setting the headers ***on a post request*** and on the server side ***i receive both 'Authorization' and 'Content-type' headers correctly.***

However, in Block (B) I am setting the headers ***on a get request*** and on the server side ***i receive both headers values as 'null'***.
I refered [this stackblitz link](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/http/stackblitz.html) to write this code.
I am struggling with this issue for past 5 days. Even after researching many SO answers and a ton of googling, i could not get this resolved. Very very frustrating. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Setting the content-type to JSON on a POST is useless: Angular does it for you. 2. Setting content-type on a GET is wrong: GET requests don't have any content, son they don't have any content type. 3. What headers are being **sent**? Look in the network panel of your browser dev tools.

Comment: Yes. I agree as i later discovered that the Content-Type was already set in my server. I just recently migrated from Http to HttpClient, and hence the code, but i was not planning on having the 'Content-type' set in the final code. After testing this a zillion times over and over, i couldn't agree with you more that the Content-type need not be explicitly set. I also had a look at the network panel of chrome and the observation is no different from the original problem. The header is set during post but not during a get.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate 'super' template with this command:
  ionic start your_app_name super
It has a helpful example using http client and header.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L868) I'd recommend trying `subscribe` instead of `pipe`, e.g.

```
getData() {
  this.http.get(this.url, {headers: myHeaders}).subscribe(res => {
    this.posts = res;
  });
}
```

See [Introduction to Angular's HttpClient](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-intro/) for more details.

Please do let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. All my requests were preflighted with 'OPTIONS' method and my server was rejecting any request which did not have a token, including the preflight 'OPTIONS' request which obviously did not have any token. I just modified my server to allow 'OPTIONS' request and everything works as expected. I thank all of you who promptly replied.